# How to customize the http status returned by @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

In a spring boot controller I am using `@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")` to check if the user is logged in(using basic auth + `JSESSIONID`).
But if the user is not logged in i.e they are not authenticated, the controller returns the `403 Forbidden`.
According to what I am known of  Authentication vs Authorization,  `401` is for Authentication while `403` is for Authorization.

As per my understanding `@PreAuthorize()` always check the authorization(as the name suggest) of the user, but is there any way to customize this on the basis of argument we pass to it, i.e `isAuthenticated()` here?

I know there is another solution: using the URL based security configuration in `configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity)`, but what if I don't want to do it this way.

Any ideas please.

Answer (score 2):

When you annotating method **A** with `@Pre/PostAuthorize` than spring will create proxy for such object and each call to such method will go through proxy (if object is under spring context).

The proxy for `@Pre/PostAuthorize` will evaluate expression from annotation (complicated here) and if it's true than pass the request father (to real method) if not than **throw AccessDaniedException**. You can also throw such exception by yourself in your method **A** and the effect will be the same. It's all about how `@Pre/PostAuthorize` works no more magic here!

But it's not the end of the story!

If `AccessDaniedException` is not suppressed or retranslated (without stack which doesn't have `AccessDaniedException`) than it will be catched by `ExceptionTranslationFilter` in Spring Security and `ExceptionTranslationFilter` will see if user is **Authenticated**

- if yes than `ExceptionTranslationFilter` will delegate to `AccessDeniedHandler` to deal with the situation and default implementation of `AccessDeniedHandler` will return **403** http code or redirect to **error page** depends if you are using rest or not.
- if not, than `ExceptionTranslationFilter` will delegate to `AuthenticationEntryPoint` and it will deal with the situation (redirect to login page, ask for http basic ... etc).

Note: `ExceptionTranslationFilter` will rethrow exception if any other than `AuthenticationException` or `AccessDeniedException` and probably **500** will be shown :(

**Your problem is probably another problem look at [Spring Security anonymous 401 instead of 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643029/spring-security-anonymous-401-instead-of-403)**

Suppressed :(:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/test/ok")
    public String getOk() {
        try {
            myService.securedMethod();
            return "ok";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info("AccessDeniedException suppressed not rethrowing :(", e);
            return "error";
        }
    }
```

Correct retranslated :) :

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/test/ok")
    public String getOk() {
        try {
            myService.securedMethod();
            return "ok";
        } catch (AccessDeniedException e) {
            throw new MyException(e); //public MyException(Throwable cause)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by using `RestControllerAdvice` and `ExceptionHandler`

```java
  @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
   public Response<ErrorResponse> exception(AccessDeniedException exception, HttpServletResponse response) {
       Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
       boolean isAuthenticated = !(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken);

       return error(
           isAuthenticated ? HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value() : HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(),
           Collections.singleton(isAuthenticated ? exception.getMessage() : "Authentication is required"),
           exception,
           response
       );
   }
```