# Invalid Response Code for Unauthorized user

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, httpwebresponse

I want my spring application to allow only admin to access **/user/*** and **/section/*.**
The application is currently blocking the request made by other users but as far as my understanding is concerned, I should get a **403** error, Instead I am getting a **401 Unauthorized** as response.

The following image is the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Here is the code which should only allow admins

```
http.csrf().disable().
                addFilterAfter(new JWTTokenGeneratorFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTTokenValidatorFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/section/*","/user/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/*").authenticated())
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
```

Please help me understand, if this behaviour is correct. I seem to be getting 401 error for all exceptions being thrown in my application.

Comment: See [Spring Security anonymous 401 instead of 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643029/spring-security-anonymous-401-instead-of-403). If it won't work, I'd like to suggest to handle `AccessDeniedException` manually